# Unable to create symbolic link

Tags: amazon-ec2, jasperserver

I'm having issues installing JasperRepors Server on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu Vm. Whenever the installation starts it gives me a "#Unable to create symbolic link /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0/common/bin/captoinfo" error. It asks me to abort  or ignore after that.